# How do I pick only one row of data per ID based on the minimum date difference in R?

Tags: r, formatting, selection

I have a dataframe with some IDs and a variable number of lines for each ID like this:

```
ID    Date_start    Date
1     2016-11-02    2020-2-22
1     2016-11-02    2015-1-18
2     2019-12-22    2017-3-2
2     2019-12-22    2019-2-9
2     2019-12-22    2017-12-1
```

And, for each ID, I'd like to keep one row only, the one with the Date closest to Date_start.
Then I'd like to set to NA all lines where the date difference between abs(Date and Date_start) is below 100 days.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Break it up into piecese. What have you tried to calculate a date difference?

Answer (score 0):

One way using `dplyr` could be to `group_by` `ID` and get the row with the minimum difference with `Date`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(-1, lubridate::ymd) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(Date_start - Date)))

#    ID Date_start Date      
#  <int> <date>     <date>    
#1     1 2016-11-02 2015-01-18
#2     2 2019-12-22 2019-02-09
```

---

If you want to set dates to `NA` you can do.

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(-1, lubridate::ymd) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(abs(Date_start - Date))) %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(Date_start - Date))) %>%
  mutate(diff = replace(diff, diff < 100, NA))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Date_start = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2016-11-02", "2019-12-22"), class = "factor"), 
Date = structure(c(5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("2015-1-18", 
"2017-12-1", "2017-3-2", "2019-2-9", "2020-2-22"), class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can get the following. I added a new ID to show how to make all values `NA`. Using Ronak's better idea of `replace` instead of `ifelse`, we can keep classes.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date_diff = abs(difftime(Date, Date_start))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(Date_diff == min(Date_diff)) %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., Date_diff < 100, NA))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID Date_start Date       Date_diff
#>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <drtn>   
#> 1     1 2016-11-02 2015-01-18 654 days 
#> 2     2 2019-12-22 2019-02-09 316 days 
#> 3     3 NA         NA          NA days
```

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), Date_start = structure(c(17107, 
17107, 18252, 18252, 18252, 18250), class = "Date"), Date = structure(c(18314, 
16453, 17227, 17936, 17501, 18202), class = "Date")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Convert factors to dates: 

cleaned_df <- within(df, {
                    Date_start <- as.Date(sapply(Date_start, as.character), "%Y-%m-%d")
                    Date <- as.Date(sapply(Date, as.character), "%Y-%m-%d")
                    }
                  )
# Aggregate to find the min Date per id: 

data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(cleaned_df, cleaned_df$ID), 
       function(x){
         data.frame(ID = unique(x$ID), Date = x$Date[which.min(x$Date_start - x$Date)])
        }
       )
      ),
 row.names = NULL
)
```

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_if(str_detect(tolower(names(.)), "date"), funs(as.Date(., "%Y-%m-%d"))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Date = Date[which.min(Date - Date_start)]) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Data thanks @Ronak Shah:

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
      Date_start = structure(
        c(1L,
          1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
        .Label = c("2016-11-02", "2019-12-22"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      Date = structure(
        c(5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L),
        .Label = c("2015-1-18",
                   "2017-12-1", "2017-3-2", "2019-2-9", "2020-2-22"),
        class = "factor"
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-5L)
  )
```